# Alternative Colour for Halberds in Lava RoboRider 8510

Tags: piece-information, sets, colour

I recently bought a second-hand lot of RoboRiders, and noticed [Lava](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8510-1#T=S) included two [halberds](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6123#T=C) in dark gray instead of black, as listed in the BrickLink inventory.

Did this set ever include dark gray halberds?

Comment: The BrickLink photo <https://www.bricklink.com/SL/8510-1.jpg?0> seems to clearly show they aren't actually black - compare with the black pieces they're attached to. So I'd guess it's either an incorrect inventory, or an alternate piece that's incompletely documented in the inventory.

Comment: @RSchulz Since these parts use a rough texture that scatters the light, they can seem a lighter colour than they really are. I did wonder about the inventory being incorrect, but some [images](https://www.picclickimg.com/d/l400/pict/393982523030_/LEGO-Technic-Roboriders-Lava-8510-Used-100-Complete.jpg) clearly show them as black, so more likely an alternate.

Comment: Based on [instructions](https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/4128784.pdf), halberds are the same color as the chassis - Black.

Comment: In the BrickLink photo, if they're black, they're the lightest black I've ever seen. The business end looks **very** different than the black pieces just south of it. But those black pieces are shiny. And perhaps it was also lit in a way that makes it an illusion that suckers me right in.

Comment: @RSchulz I believe that may be the case! It's like that notorious dress... I haven't found any images online with undoubtedly grey halberds, so I believe black is the only correct colour for them, and my seller didn't realise (I bought them as incomplete anyway, so had no expectation)